# Generate prime numbers recursively, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate prime numbers recursively using the previous primes. 2 is a prime by default and each time I keep adding 1 to the next number and divide by the previous primes, eg 2+1=3 so i check that 2 does not divide 3 so 3 is prime so i store 2 and 3 so far, next would be 3+1=4, i would use my current prime list 2 and 3, and see that 2 divides 4 so it does not go into the list then i continue with 4+1 and so forth all the way up to n. The key thing is dividing by the previous primes each time and if you reach a prime the list is updated. Please check my program to see what i am doing wrong.

this is my program so far but I am just getting 3 and 962, i want it update the list and refer back to it each time for the loop so i can use mod(2+numba,primlist) each time:

```
n=960;
primlist=[];
for numba=2:n  
   if mod(2+1,2)~=0
     primlist=2+1;
   end

   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0
     primlist=[primlist;2+numba];
   end
end
primlist
```

Comment: well, `mod(2+1, 2)` is always `mod(3, 2)` which is 1 which is never 0. Is this homework?

Comment: no it is not homework, it is for research. mod(2+1,2) is a jump start for the list if that is a proper word, so from then on i use the current primlist to get the updated primlist each time, so that is why you see the mod(2+numba,primlist) as 2+numba is always greater than 3.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was the point Parag made in their answer. I was trying to lead you to that understanding (reason I asked is that this way of looking for primes is a common homework question, and then rather than giving a straight answer I'd give hints instead, pretty standard around here).

Comment: Type `edit primes` in your command window.

Comment: Oh no no lol, no homework, i just do research in math, my professor told me that it would be more efficient to generate prime numbers than using the built in function for what I want to do. I will use the primes to calculate the diviosr function for various numbers. But thanks for your concerns ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your `primlist` again and again. Do not do that. I am making as less modifications to your code to make it run correctly. The logic is essentially correct. You just need to initialize `primlist` outside.

```
n=960;
primlist=2;
for numba=1:n  %Changed 2 to 1
   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0
      primlist=[primlist;2+numba];
   end
end
primlist
```

Comment: Thanks parag, that is exactly what i wanted! thanks!